# Image layering in Tkinter, Python [figured it out (smacks forehead)]

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I am working with a graphics module called cTurtle, which builds upon TKinter. Each controllable 'Turtle' has an image assigned to it with TKinter. I am trying to add a method to the module that will allow me to change the layering position of a given 'Turtle'. Or to put it another way, i want to add a method that will allow me to put a given image on top of the displaylist. When i call the method i have made, i get this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\login\Desktop\pYTHON EXPERIMENTS\canvastest.py", line 22, in <module>
    bob.visUp()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\login\Desktop\pYTHON EXPERIMENTS\jTurtle.py", line 2017, in visUp
    titem = self.turtle._item
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\login\Desktop\pYTHON EXPERIMENTS\jTurtle.py", line 542, in _visUp
    def _visUp(self, item):
  File "<string>", line 1, in type
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2325, in type
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'type', tagOrId) or None
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".16847312"
```

Does someone recognize why the function is rejecting what i passed to it?  The number in quotes appears to be an object id, which should work.

EDIT
well, i did myself a great disservice here by not pasting everything involved. I coded these new methods several days ago, and have been trying to debug since. Turns out i coded them right the first time. The problem was in how i called them. I added the visup() test line after exitOnClick(), meaning that the widget had, in fact, already been destroyed.
But, hey, i coded it right the first time! sorta...

Comment: Can you please paste the code of the method you made and any additional custom code involved. It's hard to say much with only this error.

Comment: We need to see the code that caused that error. It appears you are trying to call the `tag_raise` command on a widget that has been destroyed.